# Check if URL contains string then create variables with url strings

Tags: php, wordpress, url, cookies

I need to check if URL contains the term: "cidades".

For example:

```
http://localhost/site/cidades/sp/sorocaba
```

So, if positive, then I need to create two or three variables with the remaining content without the " / ", in this case:

```
$var1 = "sp";
$var2 = "sorocaba";
```

These variables will be cookies values in the beggining of the page, then, some sections will use as wp-query these values to filter.

Comment: 1. Have you tried something ? 2. So if the term is found you want all values followed by that term separated by a slash in a separate variable, *right* ?

Comment: Yes @Rizier123, I tried. I know how to check if the term is present, but couldn't find the second part.

Comment: ^ Then include your current code into your question and show/explain where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

Here I check with [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) if the search word is in the url `$str` between two slashes. If yes I get the [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) from the url after the search word and [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) it into an array with a slash as delimiter. Then you can simply loop through the array an create the variables with [complex (curly) syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex).

```
<?php

    $str = "http://localhost/site/cidades/sp/sorocaba";
    $search = "cidades";

    if(preg_match("~/$search/~", $str, $m, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
        $arr = explode("/", substr($str, $m[0][1]+strlen($m[0][0])));

        foreach($arr as $k => $v)
            ${"var" . ($k+1)} = $v;

    }

    echo $var1 . "<br>";
    echo $var2;

?>
```

output:

```
sp
sorocaba
```

Comment: It's returning to me different results.. I'm using $str = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Comment: @TiagoRossi What is the output of `var_dump($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);` ?

Comment: string(34) "/superprocura/cidades/sp/sorocaba" 
and when we change to the web server, it will be only "/cidades/state/city"

Comment: @TiagoRossi Works perfectly fine for me: http://3v4l.org/Hfn0A same for the second one: http://3v4l.org/Mjomt

Comment: Now worked. In you first answer it was $m[0][5], but in your live test it is $m[0][1] Well, hey can you help me? How can I talk to u in private?

Comment: @TiagoRossi Yeah your right, don't know how this got to 5. Corrected now.  *How can I talk to u in private?* No you can't, if you have a question you can ask it on SO, and if it is about PHP I definitely see it.

Comment: Thanks! If u can check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30651529/wordpress-url-sessions-cookies-or-get-using-different-custom-post-types

Answer (score 0):

Here are two functions that will do it for you:

```
function afterLast($haystack, $needle) {
    return substr($haystack, strrpos($haystack, $needle)+strlen($needle));
}
```

And PHP's native [`explode`](http://php.net/explode).

First call `afterLast`, passing the `/cidades/` string (or just `cidades` if you don't expect the slashes).  Then take the result and `explode` on `/` to get your resulting array.

It would look like:

```
$remaining_string = afterLast('/cidades/', $url);
$items = explode('/', $remaining_string)
```

Just note that if you do *not* include the `/` marks with the `afterLast` call, your first element in the `explode` array will be empty.

I think this solution is better, since the resulting array will support any number of values, not just two.